# angular 6 interceptor is called after request is sent

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I'm working on an angular 6 app where I want to add an jwt-token to the authorize-header of every request. For this scenario I want to use an interceptor.

The code looks like this:

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
    if (sessionId) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionId}`
        }
      });

      console.log("With AuthHeader");
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Here is my code for sending the request:

```js
  httpQuery(ressource): Observable<T[]> {
    var absoluteUrl = this.getAbsoluteUrl(ressource);
    console.log("Sending");
    return this.httpClient
      .get<T[]>(absoluteUrl);
  }
```

However I face the following problem:
The interceptor gets fired, but AFTER the request is sent. I can see this in developer console where the log-message from the http-method comes right before the log-message from the interceptor:
[image]

As you can see, this leeds to a 401 response from the server which expects the authorization-header.

I read a ton of tutorials and stackoverflow-questions about interceptor, but I can't see my mistake.

Maybe some of guys have a hint for me?

Thank you and best regards,
Alex

Comment: Please check your network tab for the request where the Authorization header is added or not.

Comment: I did and it is not sent (with different browsers). Interesting side note: fiddler doesn't notice this particular request at all. Every request I make is captured by fiddler, but this one request which results in a 401-response not. Only Wireshark captures this request and the response. And in Wireshark there is no authorization-header as well.

Comment: I have the same issue did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes it's working for a while. Thing is, I have no idea what I changed to make it work. The actual code looks very similar to what I posted. Here are some suggestions: make sure, that there is no asynchronous task to fetch the token or something, which finishes when the request is already sent. Second approach, play around with cloning the request object. In newer angular versions the headers-collection is immutable which is tricky to handle. log your request object to the console to make sure that the header is set.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is just fine

```
console.log("Sending"); //here you print to the cosole
return this.httpClient // here you actually MAKE http call.
  .get<T[]>(absoluteUrl);
```

So your interceptor is called DURING request execution and BEFORE actual XHR request is made.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. As you can see in the screenshot, the error (which occurs because of the 401 response from the server) is catched BEFORE the interceptor is executed, too. And also, apart from the log, the authorization-header not gets sent whith the request...

Comment: No, this is just how browser console works. Order of printout is not guaranteed and might be delayed in case of objects (exception here). I faces similar wtf issue in the past.

Comment: This may be true but as I said, apart from the log it doesn't work

Comment: And that is the different part of story. You can see in the broser what kind of request is actually made and you will see that probably bearer is there.

Comment: I checked the actual request in the network-tab of different browsers as well as in wireshark and I can say, there is no authorization-header

Comment: Maybe session id is not there as it is the required condition in your code. No need to use wireshark, web console is enought.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this one

```
const headers = request.headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${sessionId}`);
const d = request.clone({ headers: headers });

return next.handle(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The interceptor was added to the providers of the CoreModule.
When I added it to the providers of the FeatureModule that did the call, it worked as expected.

This is not very convenient of course but works for me at this point because I only have one FeatureModule :)